# Quantitative deformation and lusternik schnirelman method

Tags: differential-equations

The  lusternik-schnirelman  method  relates the  topology  of  manifolds with  the critical points of  functionals defined on them, giving lower bounds for the  number  of critical points  in  terms  of the  lusternik-schnirelmann category.

Is there some reference for the lusternik-schnirelman method (ensuring existence of at least cat(x) critical points for a functional defined on a banach manifold (x), in the  context of quantitative deformation, as  understood  by Willem?).

The functional is not asumed  to satisfy palais-smale condition (guaranteed  by a deformation property with respect to compact critical sets), but rather  a  quantitative deformation lemma with  respect to  possibly noncompact critical sets.

Answer (score 2):

I happened to wirte something about that, in old times.  As explained  in the introduction and in the last section, the idea is that in the application one should consider the given functional on a suitable submanifold *with boundary*, where a corresponding form of the Palais-Smale condition holds, and apply a Lusternik Schnirel'man theory there.

http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/topology/Topology%20Vol%2034/Majer_Two-variational-methods-on-manifolds-with-boundary_1995.pdf

Comment: (PS: due to a curious typo in the first lines the manifold $M$ is also denoted $N$) 